# How to perform spatial join and obtain attribute in python/GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, vector, ogr, spatial-join

I am working on a script that will take an unprojected raster, and using a UTM grid (shapefile), will obtain the correct SRS (I have a shapefile where each zone is attributed with its numerical SRS) and perform a warp/projection using GDAL on that raster.  It is a quicker way than figuring out the right zone, and then manually doing the warp.

Procedurally, I am grabbing the raster corners and constructing WKT geometry (polygon); the objective is to do a spatial join with the correct feature in the UTM grid.  Here's what I have so far:

```
import os
import ogr
from osgeo import gdal

def getRasterBox(raster):
    src = gdal.Open(raster)
    ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres = src.GetGeoTransform()
    lrx = ulx + (src.RasterXSize * xres)
    lry = uly + (src.RasterYSize * yres)
    return (uls, uly, lrx, lry)

def findUTMzone(raster_box, utmgrid):
    # do the stuff

utmzone_path = r'C:\temp'
utmzone_file = 'utm_grid.shp'
utmzone = os.path.join(utmzone_path, utmzone_file)

utm_ds = ogr.Open(utmzone)
utm_layer = utm_ds.GetLayer()

rasterdir = r'C:\temp'
raster_file = 'n38.tif'
raster = os.path.join(rasterdir, raster_file)

rasterdetails = getRasterBox(raster)
rasterWKT = 'POLYGON(({} {}, {} {}, {} {}, {} {}, {} {}))'.format(rasterdetails[0], rasterdetails[1], rasterdetails[0], rasterdetails[3], rasterdetails[2], rasterdetails[3], rasterdetails[2], rasterdetails[1], rasterdetails[0], rasterdetails[1])
```

Using the QuickWKT plugin for QGIS, I can see that I'm getting a good WKT ring for the raster bounds.  However, I'm unsure how to perform the spatial join in a way that grabs the feature attribute containing the correct SRS code.  How do I do this part (under `def findUTMzone(raster_box, utmgrid):`)?  I have seen a few `arcpy` examples, but am looking for something open-source.

Comment: Are you open to a QGIS python solution?

Comment: Not married to one approach. I can easily change the interpreter for the project to pyqgis, but would need a little extra help on the glue code, as i'm not familiar with the qgis.core package.

Comment: Using Q the general logic would be to search for "pyqgis standalone app", then "pyqgis create layer or in-memory layer from bbox coordinates", and finally "pyqgis spatial join".  If you pull all this logic together and update your question and let us know where you are stuck I'm sure someone will be able to help you out.

Comment: Perhaps the better question is: how do I do a spatial join with GDAL/OGR?  Is such a thing possible?  Currently I have no problems creating a geometry from bbox.  I just want to take geometry A and spatial join it to shapefile b.

Comment: Have you seen this post, http://www.spatialthoughts.com/blog/gis/ogr-spatial-join/

Comment: Thanks for the info, these are all helpful on a conceptual level.